# Vlookup in Excel returns #VALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am using two worksheets in Excel but am having problems with using VLOOKUP.

Sheet 1:-

```
ID    CATEGORY_ID
```

Sheet 2:-
    CATEGORY_ID    CATEGORY_NAME

I essentially want to add the CATEGORY_NAME in the 3rd column of sheet 1, so I am using the following:-

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!A2:A20+Sheet2!A2:B20,2,FALSE)
```

However, this only returns:-

```
#VALUE!
```

There are 17000 rows in worksheet 1. All rows have a category ID. Worksheet 2 only has 20 rows, including the header row (so 19 unique category ID/names).
What am I doing wrong here? Driving me insane!

Comment: What are you trying to do in parameter 2? You entered "Sheet2!A2:A20+Sheet2!A2:B20", which is a sum of two ranges?? Try only Sheet2!$A$2:$B$20 instead. Note: Add the $ signs to keep the lookup range constant, otherwise, the range will move relative together with your formula copying.

Comment: I'm not sure - I tried using Excel's function tool and must have made a mess of it - but it's now working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(made the comment an answer as it solved it)
You entered "Sheet2!A2:A20+Sheet2!A2:B20", which is a sum of two ranges?? Try only Sheet2!$A$2:$B$20 instead. Note: Add the $ signs to keep the lookup range constant, otherwise, the range will move relative together with your formula copying